# Classification with J48 and IBk (KNN) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, weka

I have given a record with many different types of mushrooms. These should be classified into edible and poisonous. The classification have to perform with k-nearest-neighbors (1) and J48.

Both algorithms shows a precision of 99.88%. Relevant for me is the false-positive rate. J48 has a rate of 0.3% and KNN of 0%. So I would say KNN is better suited for the chosen problem.

However, I dont know an answer why. Is there a general a answer why KNN is bether for some records than the J48?

The second thing is that I should use a 10-fold-cross-validation. What is that exatly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a general a answer why KNN is bether for some records than the J48?

No. It depends strongly on the dataset, the settings for both algorithms and the way you're doing the evaluation (you did use separate training and test sets, didn't you?).

10-fold cross validation means: you split your dataset in 10 equally-sized "folds", then for each of those folds *i*

- train on all the other nine folds
- evaluate on fold *i*

and take the average accuracy. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) or any book on machine learning.

Comment: No, I used only one data set (*.arff-File with attributes and the classes).

Comment: @user1147739: then your results are entirely invalid. You should always have separate training and test sets for evaluation, or use cross-validation. Again, see any book on machine learning.

Comment: But how I said, I used 10-fold cross validation. Then my results aren't ivalid?

Yes, I will read... ;-)

Comment: @user1147739 I you same data for training and testing KNN accuracies are artificially inflated. Assume K=1 for example. The nearest point is the point itself and its prediction is always going to be right. But once you start using it on the "field" (i.e. on mushrooms that dont have labels) you will start to observe problems.